# Prove that if $R$ is transitive, then $R^{-1}$ is transitive.

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $R \subseteq A \times A$. If $R$ is transitive, then $R^{-1}$
>   is transitive too.

My attempt:

Suppose $R \subseteq A \times A$ and $R$ is transitive.

Suppose we have some $x,y,z$ such that $(x,y) \in R^{-1}$ and $(y,z) \in R^{-1}$.

Then $(y,x) \in R$ and $(z,y) \in R$.

Since $R$ is transitive, we conclude that $(z,x) \in R$.

Since $(z,x) \in R$, we have $(x,z) \in R^{-1}$.

Arbitrary elements were considered.

Therefore, $R^{-1}$ is transitive. $\Box$

---

Is it correct?

Comment: Not only is it a correct proof, it's pretty much the only proof.

Comment: See this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2713698/if-r-is-a-transitive-relation-then-r-circ-is-also-a-transitive-relation-p?rq=1).